# FFMPEG Increment filename past 1000 and reset from 1

Tags: ffmpeg

From the documentation:

`ffmpeg -i video.webm image-%03d.png`

This will extract 25 images per second from the file video.webm and save them as image-000.png, image-001.png, image-002.png up to image-999.png. If there are more than 1000 frames then the last image will be overwritten with the remaining frames leaving only the last frame.

Is there any way to increment this number past 1000, and can I also have this restart from 1 so that we're not just overwriting the last frame?

I have a script that analyzes these images as they come in so I use locally stored images as a buffer/queue. It's also useful for me to have more images stored so I can go back and debug anything, so being able to do the above would be quite helpful for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
ffmpeg -i video.webm image-%04d.png
```

Will output `image-0001.png`, etc, allowing you to go beyond 999.